# Display several photos in several rows AND columns with a repeat

Tags: xpages

I would like display photos in a window on several rows and 3 columns.

image1     image2      image3

image4     image5      image6

image7     image8      image9

image10    image11     image12

Actually I find to put photo1, 2 and 3 and the others are behind photo3 but not visible...

image1    image2    image3   [image4   image5   image6   image7 ....]

This is my code :

```
<xp:table>
                <xp:tr> 
                <xp:repeat id="picturesRpt" value="#{dsvListePhoto}"
                    indexVar="i" var="picture" rows="3" >

                    <xp:panel>
                        <xp:this.data>
                            <xp:dominoDocument var="pictureDoc"
                                action="openDocument"
                                documentId="#{javascript:picture.getUniversalID()}"
                                ignoreRequestParams="true">
                            </xp:dominoDocument>
                        </xp:this.data>

                        <xp:div>
                            <xp:td>
                            <xp:div styleClass="listePhotos">
                                <xp:div>                                            
                                        <xp:image id="image1">
                                            <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript: "http://monserveur/devpt/Xpages/xphoto/PhotoWeb.nsf/" + compositeData.vueUtilisee + "/" + pictureDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID() + "/$File/TIMBRE_image.jpg?OpenElement"}]]></xp:this.url>
                                        </xp:image>
                                        <xp:text
                                            value="#{pictureDoc.Titre}" />
                                                                        <xp:br></xp:br>
                                </xp:div>
                                <xp:div>
                                    <xp:text
                                        value="#{pictureDoc.IdNiveau1} / #{pictureDoc.IdNiveau2}" />
                                </xp:div>

                        </xp:div>
                    </xp:panel>                 

                </xp:repeat>
                </xp:tr>
                </xp:table>
```

An idea ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you decided to create a **table** with three columns *finish and start a table row* every three pictures. Add `</tr><tr>` to rendered HTML whenever a new table row shall start. That is the case when indexVar i is 3, 6, 9, and so on.

[image]

Add the `</tr><tr>` tags with a computed field of content type HTML and use the rendered condition

```js
(i > 0) && (i%3 == 0)
```

Your code would look like this:

```xml
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:repeat
            id="picturesRpt"
            value="#{dsvListePhoto}"
            indexVar="i"
            var="picture"
            rows="1000">
            <xp:text escape="false">
                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    (i > 0) && (i%3 == 0)   }]]></xp:this.rendered>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    "</tr><tr>"             }]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:td>
                ... picture ...
            </xp:td>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @Modulo or some other maths tool to work out the remainder of a division by 3. That will allow you to compute whether to add Computed Text that adds a "" or a "" tag.

I did a similar demo with two columns in the Repeats on Steroids page of my IBM Connect 2013 session with Mike McGarel. The link for the slides and demo database is on my blog, at the bottom of the article, below the youtube video http://www.intec.co.uk/session-slides-and-sample-database-from-ibm-connect/

It was also delivered as a TLCC webinar, though I can't find the link. From Niklas Heidloff's blog it looks like a video was taken http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/16.04.2013093214NHEAUQ.htm

Comment: sorry I don't found the exemple. You say I use modulo, ok I understand but after how add "</tr><tr>" in the code ?

Comment: Here's the link directly to the download http://www.intec.co.uk/session-slides-and-sample-database-from-ibm-connect/bp206-twelve-tasks/. A Computed Field control allows you to enter any text, including HTML.