# Xpages control for displaying multi-value field in table form

Tags: xpages

I have a location form that has a field called Employees that is multi-value (obviously contains list of employees.

In the Location XPages I want to display the list of employees in a table form like so

```
FirstLast1       FirstLast2       FirstLast3
FirstLast4       FirstLast5       FirstLast6
FirstLast7       FirstLast8       etc.
```

I have looked at a DataTable, Repeat, etc. but nothing seems to work right. I could use a computed field with HTML but that seems like too much work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25838283/2065611 how to do it.

Comment: Knut you are fast...I certainly will look there. Thanks much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display several photos in several rows AND columns with a repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782095/display-several-photos-in-several-rows-and-columns-with-a-repeat)